# Convert list of Java objects with JTS geom to GeoJson

Tags: geojson, java, jts-topology-suite

I have a list of Java POJOs that all have a JTS geometry associated with them (Point) - a list of POIs, basically.

I want to output them as GeoJson (FeatureCollection, Feature etc.)

jackson-datatype-jts (https://github.com/bedatadriven/jackson-datatype-jts) will encode JTS Points into GeoJSON, but not a list of objects.

geojson-jackson (https://github.com/opendatalab-de/geojson-jackson) will let me make FeatureCollections and Features with geometries, but uses it's own classes for Geometries so I'd have to convert all of JTS to theirs.

That's not that complicated, but is there any Java library that will let me create proper GeoJson documents out of Java objects with JTS geometries? I started looking at GeoTools but can't really find any example that does that.

Comment: Have you looked at the current JTS version (Locationtech)? I suppose it has i/o for GeoJSON. OpenJUMP has also GeoJSON driver and source code might give you some inspiration.

Comment: I did, but looks like newer versions of JTS only serialize Geometry objects, not arbitrary objects with JTS geometries inside.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at  [`GeometryJSON`](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/geojson/geom/GeometryJSON.html) from [GeoTools](http://geotools.org) you will see the [`write` method](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/geojson/geom/GeometryJSON.html#write-org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry-java.lang.Object-) which should do what you need.

Comment: It seems like this would simply serialize the geometry, not the whole object. I want to get a JSON FeatureCollection array of Features as a result.

Comment: there is a GeoJSONDatastore that will serialize a GeoTools feature collection but if you want arbitrary POJOs you will need another lib + the GeoTools geometry handler.